# Email Contents of CSV to a Table

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of developing a powershell script that takes data from a five-column, comma-delimiter CSV and loads it into a five column HTML table for emailing. Currently, the code only outputs one row instead of the 15 rows in the CSV file. Can you help me printing the 15 rows from the CSV to the table?

```
$current_date = Get-Date
$current_date.ToUniversalTime()

$server_name = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$file = Get-Content .\data_file.csv 
Write-Output "file length: " $file.Length
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $file.Length; $i++) {
    $firstname = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[0];
    $lastname = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[1]; 
    $gender = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[2]; 
    $age = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[3];
    $dob = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[4];
}

$mailsender = @{
    Body = "<p style='font-family: Calibri;'>Audit Report as of: $current_date</p>
<table style='border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Calibri;'>
    <tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;background-color:#f7f7f7;'>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>First Name</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Last Name</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Gender</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Age</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>DoB</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$firstname</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$lastname</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$gender</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$age</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$dob</td>
    </tr>
</table>"
    From = 'john.doe@email.com'
    To = 'john.doe@email.com'
    SmtpServer = 'mailhost.net'
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Subject = "[$env:COMPUTERNAME] Audit Report"
}

Send-MailMessage @mailsender
```

Comment: You should try the `Import-Csv` cmdlet instead of your `for`-loop. It will import the file and enables you to read the columns way easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to define a variable in your for loop and add each set of table rows to it, then call the variable in your Body declaration:

```
$current_date = Get-Date
$current_date.ToUniversalTime()

$server_name = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$file = Get-Content .\data_file.csv 
Write-Output "file length: " $file.Length
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $file.Length; $i++)
{ 
$firstname = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[0] ;
$lastname = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[1] ; 
$gender = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[2] ; 
$age = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[3] ; 
$dob = ([string]$file[$i]).Split(',')[4] ;

$data += "<tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$firstname</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$lastname</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$gender</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$age</td>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$dob</td>
    </tr>"
}

$mailsender=@{
Body="<p style='font-family: Calibri;'>Audit Report as of: $current_date</p>
<table style='border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Calibri;'>
    <tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;background-color:#f7f7f7;'>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>First Name</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Last Name</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Gender</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Age</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>DoB</th>
    </tr>
    $data
</table>"
From='john.doe@email.com'
To='john.doe@email.com'
   SmtpServer='mailhost.net'
    BodyAsHtml=$true
    Subject="[$env:COMPUTERNAME] Audit Report"
}

Send-MailMessage @mailsender
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Import-Csv` to read your data and `ConvertTo-Html` to convert it to HTML. Add CSS as a header.

```
$style = @'
<style>
table {font-family: Calibri;}
th {border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;background-color:#f7f7f7;}
tr {border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;}
</style>
'@

$mailsender = @{
    'Body' = Import-Csv .\data_file.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Header $style
    ...
}
```

If you need to put additional content into the HTML body, not just the table, convert your date to a HTML fragment and use that fragment in building the final HTML:

```
$data = Import-Csv .\data_file.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
$html = @"
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {font-family: Calibri;}
th {border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;background-color:#f7f7f7;}
tr {border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Some text.</p>
${data}
</body>
</html>
"@

$mailsender = @{
    'Body' = $html
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlet `Import-Csv` will serve you better than string-splitting. Try importing the CSV and creating your rows in a loop like so:

```
$current_date = Get-Date
$current_date.ToUniversalTime()

$server_name = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$csv = Import-Csv ".\my_file.csv"
$html = ""
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $html += "<tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>"
    $html += "<th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$($row.firstname)</td>"
    $html += "<th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$($row.lastname)</td>"
    $html += "<th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$($row.gender)</td>"
    $html += "<th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$($row.age)</td>"
    $html += "<th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>$($row.dob)</td>"
    $html += "</tr>"
}

$mailsender = @{
    Body       = "<p style='font-family: Calibri;'>Audit Report as of: $current_date</p>
<table style='border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Calibri;'>
    <tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;background-color:#f7f7f7;'>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>First Name</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Last Name</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Gender</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>Age</th>
        <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>DoB</th>
    </tr>
    $html    
</table>"
    From       = 'john.doe@email.com'
    To         = 'john.doe@email.com'
    SmtpServer = 'mailhost.net'
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Subject    = "[$env:COMPUTERNAME] Audit Report"
}
```